# Task ContinuewWith await returning error

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have the following code that uses `System.Threading.Tasks`

```
private async void UploadDocument(System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    var someTask = await Task.Run<bool>(() =>
    {
        // open input stream
        using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(FileTextBox.Text, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (StreamWithProgress uploadStreamWithProgress = new StreamWithProgress(stream))
            {
                uploadStreamWithProgress.ProgressChanged += uploadStreamWithProgress_ProgressChanged;

                // start service client
                FileTransferWCF.FileTransferServiceClient client = new FileTransferWCF.FileTransferServiceClient();
                //FileTransferClient.FileTransferServiceClient client = new FileTransferClient.FileTransferServiceClient();

                // upload file
                client.UploadFile(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length, uploadStreamWithProgress);

                // close service client
                client.Close();
            }
        }

        return true;

    }).ContinueWith(r =>{
        if(r.Result) LogText("Done!!");
    });

}
```

If I leave this and try to compile I get:

> "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable"** in the
>   `var someTask`

So I then change `var someTask` to `Task someTask` but now I get the error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'".

Any clue on how to deal with this?

Comment: You really should follow Stephen's model from your previous question.  It's the proper way to design this system.  As I commented there, the logging shouldn't even be in `UploadDocument` in the first place, it should be in the caller.

Comment: Side not: **Never write `async void`**. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/02/18/talk-the-new-async-design-patterns.aspx

Comment: What should I use? I saw in your link that void is ok only in handlers and mine is not :( Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `await` keyword waits for a task to finish and returns the **result**.

It does not return the task itself.

Since your `ContinueWith()` doesn't have a result (it returns `Task`, not `Task<T>`), your `await` expression returns `void`, which obviously cannot be assigned to a variable.

You can simplify your code like this:

```
await Task.Run(() => {
    using (...) {
        ...
    }
});
LogText("Done!");
```

Comment: Ok I can get rid of await, but then how can I make the task to execute async?

Comment: @VAAA What do you mean? SLaks isn't saying that you should get rid of `await`, he's saying you should get rid of `ContinueWith()`.